# Migrating application signatures Eclipse between Windows and Linux

Tags: android, eclipse, migration, signature, workspace

I've moved my workspace and successfully managed to get it to work on Linux (Ubuntu 11.04) my problem lays on the fact that I can't remember how I did this when I did it for my mac. I'm getting the *"Re-installation failed due to different application signatures."* error since I don't have the signature in Linux.

My question would be, how to move the application signature from windows to linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get this error,If you want to install same application with some changes.Uninstall the previous one and install again

Comment: Sorry Rasel but you are mistaken. I'm developing an application that's already on the market and therefore needs to have a consistent signature key to be able to update instead of uninstall + install the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the Debug or the Release keystore?

You used the release keystore to sign your app before uploading it to the Android Market. So to upgrade this same app later you need that same keystore file. Without this keystore you're lost and you need to upload a newer release with a new packagename and signature.

If you are talking about the Debug key - it must be somewhere in your users environment. You can see the default location in Eclipse (Window/Preferences/Android/Build).

Comment: I meant the debug one, but solved that by copying it from .android in my home folder. As for the Release keystore, that's giving me problems now, where should I look for it

Comment: Nobody knows but you. Sorry. When you did create the keystore file you did issue the commands in a folder of your choice. If you do have your old Windows Eclipse installation you could try to sign again and hope that Eclipse uses that old directory... I always create a folder called release within my Android projects. In this folder I create the release keystore. That way I do have everything in the same root directory.

Comment: What file am I looking for? I mean, what extension

Comment: Usually they are named *.keystore

Comment: It actually didn't have an extension, it was the name of the package name dom.package.name, whatever I set that to when I created. And it was located at c:/Eclipse/* in case that's the default or something that might help others.

Comment: If you did use the command line tool "keytool" it will store the file in the current working directory. Never used Eclipse for that. In that case c:\eclipse\ sounds reasonable... Glad you found it.